# MKAnnotationView stealing touches from MKMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I have a map view with lots of custom annotations. The problem is that there are so many of them that you're very likely to hit an annotation when you're trying to zoom. The annotation steals the touch and you're unable to zoom.

I would like it to work like a table view: When you start dragging, the cell is deselected and the table view starts scrolling. Does anyone know how to accomplish this with `MKMapView`?

If not, is there some third party map view which does what I want?

Answer (score 0):

How are you detecting touches on the pins? If you are using the standard map view delegate callbacks then it should take care of this issue for you.

Comment: We're using `UIButton`s, because we need to respond to `UIControlEventTouchDown`. Our annotations doesn't work like pins.

Comment: I would recommend using normal pins and gesture recognizers. Otherwise you'll have to do some special touch detection and determine delta's vs time to see if they are zooming.

Answer (score 0):

Since zoom requires multiple touches why not check for that versus a tap? Add to that something where you can decide when to kill competing gestures such as the touch point being within the frame of one of your subclassed annotation views:

`gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer)`